# Xamarin POST Request headers

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, http-post

Hola amigos quiero mandar un **POST** desde **Xamarin** , pero estoy obteniendo este error cuando trato de mandarlo y quisiera saber si estoy mandando mis **headers** correctamente. Cuando lo trato de mandar mi app se detiene y me tira un error que dice

> System.InvalidOperationException: Content-Type

Esta es mi función

```js
public async void Access_Api(string userName, string pass, string tok_ty, string acc_tok) {

  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(tok_ty, acc_tok);
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-version", "1.0");
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  var values = new Dictionary < string,
    string > {
      {
        "usuario",
        "prueba"
      },
      {
        "contraseña",
        "prueba123"
      },
      {
        "idusuario",
        "1"
      },
    };


  var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

  var response = await client.PostAsync("http://somewhereintheinternet.com:80/some/where",
    content);

  switch (response.StatusCode) {
    case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK):
      res_Label.Text = "good";
      break;

    case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest):
      res_Label.Text = "no good";
      break;

    case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden):
      res_Label.Text = "no good, Forbidden";
      break;

  }


}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has usado Postman para verificar que la API funcione adecuadamente?

Comment: SI patrón por su puesto, el error me lo manda desde **VS**

Comment: reemplaza esta linea asi client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Comment: ¿Has intendado quitarle esa línea del content type?

Comment: Como dice @fredyfx no necesitas la linea del content-type

Comment: @fredyfx y Jesus Angulo los amo con cada fibra de mi ser :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detalle en el comentario del código:

```
public async void Access_Api(string userName, string pass, string tok_ty, string acc_tok) {

  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(tok_ty, acc_tok);
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-version", "1.0");

  //La siguiente línea es innecesaria:  
  //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  var values = new Dictionary < string,
    string > {
      {
        "usuario",
        "prueba"
      },
      {
        "contraseña",
        "prueba123"
      },
      {
        "idusuario",
        "1"
      },
    };


  var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

  var response = await client.PostAsync("http://somewhereintheinternet.com:80/some/where",
    content);

  switch (response.StatusCode) {
    case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK):
      res_Label.Text = "good";
      break;

    case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest):
      res_Label.Text = "no good";
      break;

    case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden):
      res_Label.Text = "no good, Forbidden";
      break;

  }


}
```